# How to Prevent Gray Color Feedback on Button Tap in .NET MAUI .NET 8

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I recently updated my .NET MAUI application to .NET 8 and have encountered a new issue with button interaction. Before the update, the visual feedback when a button was tapped (changing to a gray color) was not an issue, but now, despite efforts to maintain the button's original background color (#5983FC) during tap interactions, the button changes to gray when tapped and then reverts back. I am looking for a way to either completely disable this gray color feedback or ensure the button's appearance remains unchanged during interaction.

Here is the XAML for my button :

```
<Border
     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
     StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10"
     StrokeThickness="5"
     Stroke="White"
     Margin="5"
     BackgroundColor="#5983FC">
 <Button 
        Text="{Binding TitleScanningButton}"
        TextColor="White"
        FontSize="32"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        BackgroundColor="#5983FC"
        Command="{Binding ScanCommand}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#5983FC" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
 </Button>
</Border>
```

To handle the button's command, I have the following method in my ViewModel, which performs various checks and triggers alerts based on certain conditions:

```
public IAsyncRelayCommand ScanCommand => _scanCommand ??= new AsyncRelayCommand(ScanForPeripherals);

private async Task ScanForPeripherals()
{
    // Method logic that includes sending messages, checking conditions,
    // displaying alerts, and performing an action based on the conditions.
}
```

I attempted to use the VisualStateManager to explicitly set the Pressed state's background color to the same as the Normal state, aiming to override the default gray color feedback. Unfortunately, this did not produce the desired effect, and the button still changes to gray when tapped.

Additionally, I tried appending to the ButtonHandler's mapping for the BackgroundColor property in my MauiProgram.cs:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ButtonHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(
    nameof(View.BackgroundColor),
    (handler, view) => handler.UpdateValue(nameof(IView.Background)));
```

This attempt also did not resolve the issue, as the button's tap feedback remains unchanged.

Is there an effective method in .NET MAUI to disable or customize this tap feedback color for a button? I'm looking for a solution that allows the button to maintain its original background color without changing to gray when pressed.

PS : The method **ScanForPeripherals** display an alert, for that reason it is dark in the second picture.

**Button before tap**
[image]
**Button after tap**
[image]

Comment: Umm you don't want animations is it?

Comment: @FreakyAli Of course, but it seems strange that updating to .net 8 changes the visuals from a light tap to gray background.

Comment: Can you visually show me what you don't want that would make my life easier

Comment: I see where you are coming from, so basically you would like to control what colour the animation takes yeah? There is bad news FYI you can't do that in MAUI directly, you have two choices basically you can either change this natively on all platforms or you can use this custom control I have created https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls, you are looking for the Button class, you can always just copy what you need, also for adding native animations to your views you could use https://freakyali.medium.com/adding-native-click-effects-in-net-maui-dd3159a4b709

Comment: If this is acceptable i can add it as an answer btw :)

Comment: @FreakyAli okay, let me try it and i will inform you!!

Comment: @FreakyAli don't you think this is a bug? I mean, I don't expect a button to stay in a pressed state until the command completes its work if that command contains asynchronous code. I've never seen this behavior in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: I have never seen this honestly, but then yeah it could be a possible bug, Ideally code that freezes your thread is generally async

Comment: @FreakyAli that's the curios thing... it doesn't freeze the UI thread. You can still interact with UI while the button is grey.

Comment: Not gonna lie that's really weird, do you see the same issue with the button i recommend from my UIKIT?

Comment: @FreakyAli  Just tested it with the UIKIT that you provided and there is nothing wrong. There is a light tap when you tap the button that one is the desirable. Okay my problem is solved if I use your kit but it seems to be a bug in .NET right?

Comment: In your case i guess it is a bug

Comment: Okay but Ι don't understand this behaviour. Anyway, I'll look into it further and if I find something I 'll inform you. Thank you very much!! @FreakyAli

Comment: Happy to help, Also should I add this as an answer?

Comment: @FreakyAli Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid issues that I generally faced with the .NET MAUI button control I created a Button control myself that you can find on https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls

Post initialization you can do whatever your regular button can do and more and it has 4 different types of click animations available to choose from

```
 <freakyControls:FreakyButton
        Animation="FadeAndScale"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
        BorderColor="Black"
        BusyColor="White"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        Text="Click me!"
        TextColor="White"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
        </freakyControls:FreakyButton.TrailingIcon>
 </freakyControls:FreakyButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug in MAUI.

You can workaround in two ways.

#### 1. Make the command `async void`

I personally don't like this way, because you should always return a `Task` when you can, but it's probably the fastest to apply and also to revert when the bug is fixed.

So your command would become

```cs
private async void ScanForPeripherals()
{
    // Method logic that includes sending messages, checking conditions,
    // displaying alerts, and performing an action based on the conditions.
}
```

#### 2. Use a `Border` instead of a `Button`

A `Border` is not subject to state changes, so you could replace your `Button` with something like this.

```xml
<Border
    BackgroundColor="#5983FC">
    <Label
        Text="{Binding TitleScanningButton}"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="32"
        FontAttributes="Bold" />
    <Border.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ScanCommand}" />
    </Border.GestureRecognizers>
</Border>
```

Comment: I dont like the first approach and also I have already a border that contains the button. ( edited the question)

Comment: @NikosBasdanis You can still use the second option